# Floated items: some end up alone in the row

Tags: html, css

So, got a pretty standard float set up.

```
<div class="container clearfix">
   <div class="item">Some content</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.item {
  float:left
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1.5%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #929292;
}
```

There are also adsense ads mixed in, but their size is contained by .item

**The problem:** One of the items (the one that's supposed to be 1st in a row) is alone on the right of the container, and the remaining items are on the next row, floated left as they are supposed to be.

The question probably been here quite a few times, but my searches didn't return anything. Wrong keywords i guess.

p.s.
i've tried changing width and margin.

Comment: where is float property?

Comment: my bad. It was in the separate class, designated for float alone. fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Some browsers round your `1.5%` up to `2%`. Could that be the problem? Because then you would have `102%` in total, causing it to break.</strike>

You could also work with paddings instead of margins, then you can set `box-sizing: border-box;`. If you do it like this, your padding will be included in the total width.

Based on your live version, here is your answer:

The item with the advertisement has a different height than your other items, that is why they appear strange. You have to either clear the floats on the first item after the advertisement, or make sure all items are of the same height.

Comment: I've tried  playing with width and margins (updated question), that's not the issue. Plus the problem appears in chrome, which almost never gives me grief with css. And i don't really want to do paddings, since there are borders involved (also not the problem), and it would require some extra containers

Comment: Could you recreate the problem in jsfiddle?

Comment: scratch that. found the problem

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that blocks with adsense were not as tall as the rest of the blocks. The width was contained, but height was not set. I've just set a fixed height, and it fixed the issue. A bit of pain in the @$$ to set for smaller resolutions, but the problem went away